# Facebook PHP SDK dealing with Access Tokens

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, access-token

I have crawled around lots of various answers but am still a bit confused with how I should be dealing with facebook **access tokens**.
One of the main problems I'm having is due to what information is being stored in my browser. For example, I log onto the app, the token expires, I can't logon again unless I clear cookies/app settings in browser.

I stumbled across this thread: [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation)

Which has shown me how to create an extended access token through php.

**My questions are:**

**1.** Do I need to store the access token anywhere?

**2.** What happens when the access token expires or becomes invalid? At the moment, my app simply stops working when the short term access ones expire.

**3.** Is there a way I should be handling them to check if they have expired?
I am using the php sdk and have basically used the standard if( $user )... Like this:

```
require 'sdk/src/facebook.php';

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));

  $user = $facebook->getUser();

  if( $user ){
    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    }
  }

  if (!$user){

    $params = array(
    'scope' => 'email',
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( $params );
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
                window.open("'. $loginUrl .'", "_self"); 
                </script>';
                exit;

 } 
     if( $user ){

    $access_token = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();     

     $get_user_json = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $access_token;

// Rest of my code here...
}
```

- Is there anything else I should be doing to handle tokens?

. Should I be passing the access token between pages or is it ok to just call it again at the top of each page like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/',
));
     $token = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();
```

Comment: From the last time I looked at the Facebook API (last year), you will need to acquire a new access token when it invalidates. You shouldn't need to pass the token between pages, but I believe each call to the API does require a signature.

Comment: @Tebc Thanks for your answer. Do you know what to do after exchanging for an extended token? I keep coming across an issue where after a couple of hours, on loading the page suddenly it is (!$user) which results in never being able to login unless browser is cleared. What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through your questions:

> Do I need to store the access token anywhere?

This depends on your application. First of all ask yourself, do you need to perform actions on behalf of the user while he is **not** present (not logged in to your app)?
If the answer is **yes**, then you need to extend the user token which can be done using the PHP-SDK by calling this method while you have a valid user session: `setExtendedAccessToken()`.

Also you should refer to this document: [Extending Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)

> What happens when the access token expires or becomes invalid? ...
>   Is there a way I should be handling them to check if they
>   have expired?

This is where the *catch* clause in your code comes in handy, while facebook example only *logs* the error (`error_log($e);`) you should be handling it!

Facebook already has a tutorial about this: [How-To: Handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/).

Also you should refer to the [Errors table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) and adjust your code accordingly.

> Is there anything else I should be doing to handle tokens?

See above.

> Should I be passing the access token between pages or is it ok to just
>   call it again at the top of each page

You shouldn't need to do any of that, because the PHP-SDK will handle the token for you; have you noticed that you are calling: `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` without appending the user `access_token`?

The SDK is adding it from its end so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but i solve it with some of your help. I'm using the php-sdk to connect to the Facebook API, so i just made this.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'API_ID', 
          'secret' => 'SECRET',
        ));

// Get User
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Verifing if user is logged in.
if ($user) {
    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    }
}

// Verify if user is logged in, if it is... Save the new token.
if($user){

   // Request the access_token to the 
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken()

   // Saving the new token at DB.
   $data = array('access_token' => $access_token);
   $this->db->where('userid',$user);            
   $this->db->update('facebook', $data);

}
```